# Default arguments in a move constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-value, move-constructor

I found this code in a book.

```
template<typename T,typename Container=std::deque<T> >
class stack
{
public:
    explicit stack(const Container&);
    explicit stack(Container&& = Container());   <<<<<< 
    //...
}
```

I am wondering when does the default value of move constructor get used?

As much I understand, in move operation there is always a source object to move from.

Comment: Isn't there any default constructor?

Comment: That does not fit the definition of a [`move constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor). It's just a regular constructor. A move constructor is not templated and is in the form of `stack(stack &&)`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: "... and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values."

Comment: Could you please mention any such case? Feel free to add as answer. :) As much I know, a non-default value would be taken when  `move(some_container)` is used as source.

Comment: `explicit stack(Container&& = Container());` allows default constructor. (note that `Container` is different than `stack`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class has exactly 1 constructor that has no non-default-valued parameters (including the default constructor), it can be used to default construct and instance of that class. In the following example, `bar::bar(foo&&)` is used to construct x :

```
struct foo {};

class bar
{
public:
    explicit bar(const foo&) {}
    explicit bar(foo&& = foo()) {}
};

int main()
{
    bar x;
}
```

This has nothing to do with templates or move semantics. For example, you can just use `int` for a much simpler example :

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(int = 0) {}
};

int main()
{
    foo x;
}
```